# Can you test Google Play In-App Billing after publishing an app?

Tags: android, testing, google-play, in-app-purchase

Our app has been published in Google Play Production for over a month and we added some IAP items after that. I wanted to do some test purchasing first before updating the production build so I decided to upload build in test channels first. To be more specific here are the approaches that I've tried.

- Uploaded in Closed Beta channel with Google Community tie-up
- Uploaded in Closed Aplha channel with Google Community tie-up
- Uploaded in Closed Alpha channel with white list of testers

With all the approaches I tried above, the purchase always seem to presented with actual charge even though the accounts used are included in the opted testers. Is there any way to resolve this or is it impossible to do some test purchases after a version of the app is published in production? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm testing IAB subscription with published app. My case fits into 3rd one you mentioned. If everything goes well, Google Play tells me the purchase is for testing and never be billed (in meaning, not with those words). And my subscription is for monthly base, with test account it renews everyday which is very handy to test cancelling/re-subscripting case.

I don't know why you are having trouble with test account. But I'm pretty sure you can.